# What do I need to parse the date correctly

Tags: c#, string, parsing, date, datetime

I'm receiving a bad parsing from the content in a database.

This is what I'm receiving and the date string.

> FORMAT EXCEPTION: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
>   There is an unknown word starting at index 20.

11/02/2013 12:30:44 p.m.

I'm using `DateTime.Parse(...)`, what do I need to change to perform the parsing?

Comment: More to the point: why are you storing datetimes as strings in the database?

Comment: @Mitch: While you make a valid comment, that may be out of the OP's control for either for historical or hysterical reasons.

Comment: It might be: but that;'s why I'm asking the question. Technical debt attacts a high interest rate...

Comment: @MitchWheat Well, I'm storing this string in a XML document, not necessary in a relational database

Comment: datetimes in a xml document should be in ISO 8601 format....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `DateTime.ParseExact()`

```
DateTime x = DateTime.ParseExact("11/02/2013 12:30:44 p.m.", "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", null)
```

- [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx)